# Pyspark SelectExp() not working for first() and last()

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark3

i have 2 statements which are to my knowledge exactly alike, but `select()` works fine, but `selectExpr()` generates following results.

```
+-----------------------+----------------------+
|first(StockCode, false)|last(StockCode, false)|
+-----------------------+----------------------+
|                 85123A|                 22138|
+-----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------+----------+
|first_value|last_value|
+-----------+----------+
|  StockCode| StockCode|
+-----------+----------+
```

following is implementation.

```
df.select(first(col("StockCode")), last(col("StockCode"))).show()
df.selectExpr("""first('StockCode') as first_value""", """last('StockCode') as last_value""").show()
```

Can any 1 explain the behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selectExpr` takes everything as `select` clause in sql.
Hence if you write anything in single quote`'`, it will act as string in sql. if you wanted to pass the column to `selectExpr` use backtique (`) as below-

```py
df.selectExpr("""first(`StockCode`) as first_value""", """last(`StockCode`) as last_value""").show()
```

backtique will help you to escape space in the column.

you can use without backtique also if your column name is not starting with number like `12col` or it doesn't have spaces in between like `column name`

```py
df.selectExpr("""first(StockCode) as first_value""", """last(StockCode) as last_value""").show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass like below

```
df_b = df_b.selectExpr('first(count) as first', 'last(count) as last')
df_b.show(truncate = False)

+-----+----+
|first|last|
+-----+----+
|2527 |13  |
+-----+----+
```